# R: xts get year or month for a certain row in a xts time series object

Tags: r, xts

How can I get for example the year of the first or last entry in a xts time series object as a string? In this example of the AAPL time series?

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
```

Answer (score 4):

Year of first entry....

```
format(index(first(AAPL)),"%Y")
```

Year of last entry...

```
format(index(last(AAPL)),"%Y")
```